# Create entries in one table dependant on data in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create entries in a second table dependent on entries in the first table.

i.e I have 2 tables.

Table one has information about originators and emails etc
Table 2 has details on security keys linked to the id of each entry in table 1

So Table 1 looks something like this#

```
ID  NAME    GROUPID DISTLIST    EMAIl
1   Entry1  Bird    Avian       a@b
2   Entry2  Dog     Canine      b@c
3   Entry3  Cat     Feline      c@d
4   Entry4  Bird    Avian       a@b
5   Entry5  Dog     Canine      b@c
6   Entry6  Cat     Feline      c@d
7   Entry7  Bird    Avian       a@b
8   Entry8  Dog     Canine      b@c
9   Entry9  Cat     Feline      c@d
10  Entry10 Moose   Big         a@b
```

There are about 200 groupid's

Table 2 looks something like this#

```
ID  TABLE1ID    Key 
1   10         hbfdvhfvsdffrfewfwef
2   5          omnoregnonerognoe    
3   3          754lwsncvhtyroe0
4   2          nvjddopeithdfnn
5   6          nvjddopeithdfnn
6   1          omnoregnonerognoe
```

Now what I am trying to do is for each ID in table one insert a line in table 2 containing its key.

This key can be the same for each of the entries under a group in table 1 so I want to add lines in table 2 for each ID in table 1 where the groupid in table 1 is dog.

So insert into table 2 ID,Table1group,Key for each Table1.id where table1.groupid = dog (this isn't the code just a view of the command structure I am looking for)

I am struggling on the SQL for this and any assistance would be most helpful as I have 18 of these tables to create and over 1000 entries in each supplying table 1's

I can and already have added a lot of data into table 2 using a manual insert into command:

```sql
insert into [table2].[App].[ApiKeys] with (rowlock)

  ([originatorId],[apiKey],[apiSecret]) VALUES ('1000346','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy')
```

but this will take me days if not weeks to do for all.

Comment: Apologies, I am writing this for a MSQL 2016 server using ssms to connect

Comment: Why are there 2 records for `Dog` in table 2? Specifically, why are there two values form table1, id's 2 and 5? Shouldn't there only be one? Only one of the ID values that in table1 correspond to `Dog`?

Comment: no Dog is a group, the name is the distinct column (and ID obviously) So for each of the ID's in table 1 where the group is dog for example I need to add an entry into table 2 so I would end up with an entry for each ID (I have renamed the columns in table 2 above to make this clearer)

Comment: Where do you take the values that need to go into KEY column in table2?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - this is not really an answer. I want to check that you know you can use INSERT with SELECT. For example you can do this...

```
INSERT INTO table2(originatorId,apiKey,apiSecret)
  SELECT id, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
    FROM table1
```

If you have more information about where the api key and secret come from I can edit this answer.

Comment: nope and that might be the connector for me can I use a when clause on that too?

Comment: Yep - you can use WHERE and WHEN (but WHEN only shows up in the CASE clauses)

Comment: Perfect thank you that works and I just inserted 312 unique entries from table 1 into table 2 where the group was dog

Comment: Splendid. We should really delete these answers - they're not going to be any use to the next visitor. But don't let that put you off using SO! I'll give you a few mins before removing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

so I missed the fact you can use a select statement within the insert statement. bit of a basic miss and feel like an idiot now

Comment: INSERT ... SELECT is not used much - it almost always introduces redundancy into your database. I feel like an idiot because I don't know what to do with this thread. It needs to be marked as completed even though my answer is not really an answer.

Comment: @SQLHacks No - <insert ... select ...> is used all the time in all sorts of ways to perform logically correct actions. This is a vast over-generalization.

Comment: Fair point I should have written "I very rarely use INSERT ... SELECT ...". My point was that OP should not beat himself up for not knowing about it.